# Mongodb find by query and group

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Simple collection:

```
[
    {
       _id: '123',
       name: 'FooBar',
       zone: 'Bas'
    },{
       _id: '456',
       name: 'Alice',
       zone: 'Bas'
    },{
       _id: '789',
       name: 'FooBar',
       zone: 'Bas'
    }
]
```

First I build a query to find all elements by name:

```
db.collection.find({name:'FooBar'})
```

How can I extend this with a group query using aggregation? I would like to group the collection by zone.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this,

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    { 
        $match : {name : "FooBar"}
    },
    { 
        $group : { 
             _id : "$zone", 
              total : { $sum : 1 } 
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: What do you execute ?

Comment: @kocko the error was related to an old mongo version (2.0.4) I updated to 2.4. now it works