# use mongoose.find but one item per user

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Good friends, I am developing an API for a project and I need to take the last messages sent to the user or sent by the user from the database. But of these messages I only want to get a maximum of 1 per user, to show a preview of the last message in the message inbox, and when selecting the chat, all the messages of each conversation would be loaded.

**Example (all messages sent to Joangel):**

from: Joel, to: Joangel, msg: sdffd

from: Joel, to: Joangel, msg: 234235

from: Joel, to: Joangel, msg: 551

from: Jorge, to: Joangel, msg: ee werwe

from: Jorge, to: Joangel, msg: sdffd55

from: Tony, to: Joangel, msg: heeey

**Should return this when using find:**

from: Joel, to: Joangel, msg: sdffd

from: Jorge, to: Joangel, msg: ee werwe

from: Tony, to: Joangel, msg: heeey

If you can help me with this I would be very grateful

Comment: You can use $group in aggregation like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/22013656/8987128

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mongoose, then you should use the model.findOne() method,
[The link for the findOne method documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne)

Basically what you should do is create a mongoose schema and model, something like,

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({name: String, message: String})
```

You may add more items to your schema, after that create your model,

```
const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema)
```

Add your users to the model
now whenever you want to perform a function with your model, you may query for it, in your case you have to use,

```
User.findOne({conditions which you use to find the specific user}, function(err, foundUser){Here you can do anything with that user which you queried for from your database})
```